# Clericulus = altar boy?

Tags: ecclesiastical-latin, song-lyrics, catechism-catholic-church

The Holy Innocents hymn [*Personent hodie*](https://www.cpdl.org/wiki/index.php/Personent_hodie) (1582) uses the word [*clericulus*](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/clericulus) in its 4<sup>th</sup> stanza:

> *Omnes clericuli, pariter pueri, cantent ut angeli*

Is a [*clericulus*](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/clericulus) an altar boy?

Altar boy = [*chierichetto*](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/chierichetto) in Italian.

Comment: At the linked website, under the the tab DuCange (my bolding): "Junior Clericus, vel **Puer Choralis**." So choir boy appears to be one possible translation. I checked Albert Sleumer, *Kirchenlateinisches Wörtberbuch*: it doesn't have an entry for clericulus.

Comment: Considering that the contrast is made with *pueri* right there, I wouldn't use a translation that has "boy" in it. It's just the diminutive of *clericus*, the intention is not to be as specific as "altar boy" or "choir boy" are anyway.

Comment: @Cairnarvon In French, altar boy = _enfant de chœur_…

Answer (score 4):

The more likely meaning is "choirboys."

> When clergy are positioned as singers and listeners in Latin song, they are typically identified by the plural cleri or the diminutive clericuli (choirboys)

From: "Singing the Refrain: Shaping Performance and Community Through Form.” Devotional Refrains in Medieval Latin Song, by Mary Channen Caldwell, Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 2022, pp. 104–147.